# execute exe from incomplete name in .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wanna make a .bat for installing service, I use that

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe "ServiceName.exe"
```

But the "v4.0.30319" can be "v4.0.otherVersion" and I look for a way to execute anyway.
I searched a lot of but didn't find something who work and I'm really bad with bash.

Thanks.

Comment: [tag:batch-file] and [tag:bash] are two completely different things! Since you are obviously working on Windows I assume the former. Anyway, what have you tried, where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Regard that this site is not a free code/script writing service, so you are expected to put in your own efforts! You should take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your provided information, this idea retrieves the location you require from the registry:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Net4RegPath=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4"
Set "InstallUtil="
For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%reg.exe Query "%Net4RegPath%" /S /F "InstallPath" /V /E
     2^>NUL^|%__AppDir__%find.exe "_SZ"')Do For /F "Delims=" %%I In (
    '%__AppDir__%where.exe "%%~H\.":"InstallUtil.exe" 2^>NUL'
)Do Set "InstallUtil=%%I"
If Defined InstallUtil "%InstallUtil%" "ServiceName.exe"
```

Please note that this will not currently retrieve the appropriate file path if you're wanting to specifically identify the location of the x86 `InstallUtil.exe` file on an x64 OS. But as that is technically outside of the scope of your question at the time of answering, I'll leave that for you to implement if required.